# How do I adjust settings in overGrive?

Tags: google-drive, grive

So, I've got overgrive installed and synced, but how do I adjust the settings? I gotta reorganize files and such.

I've tried opening the program and it just has a spinning wheel and then nothing, no GUI.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the overGrive menu select Preferences to change the settings.

Lubuntu / LXDE / Mint desktop users and users that use Light Themes need to select the **Prefer Light Icon Theme** or they might not be able to see the default white application indicator icon in the taskbar. Also see [notes and instructions](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu) for Gnome desktop users.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the bar at the bottom of your desktop and select "+ add applets to the panel".

From the list of applets highlight "System Tray" and click "+ add to panel".

You should now see the OverGrive icon on the panel.  Which when you click on it will display the settings menu.

I hope this solves your issue.